# Policies auth on expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, policies

How can I  integrate the way of doing policies in SailsJs  into a basic expressJs project?

[The way of doing policies in SailsJs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies)

Answer (score 1):

I'd read about middleware [The way of doing middleware in Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)
and passport.js [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/)

You need to intercept the request using middleware, get the credentials, validate them, then either move the request on to be fullfilled, or reject with a 401 unauthorised.